# Visual Studio shows Invalid Value Warnings for integer properties in Razor Views

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor

### Issue description

I am having two warnings in a Razor Partial View in Visual Studio which state:

- `@Model.TotalCount` is not a valid value of attribute `max`
- `@Model.CurrentCount` is not a valid value of attribute `value`

### Code example

This is a fragment of the **Razor code** from the `_CarList.cshtml`:

```html
@model ICarList

...

<progress id="car-list-progress-bar"
          max="@Model.TotalCount"
          value="@Model.CurrentCount"></progress>
...
```

And here's the **C# definition of the interface** used in that view:

```cs
public interface ICarList : IList<CarListItem>
{
    int CurrentCount { get; }
    int TotalCount { get; }
    int StartFrom { get; }
    int PreviousCount { get; }
    bool HasPrevious { get; }
    bool HasMore { get; }
}
```

You can see the **warnings** in this screenshot:

[image]

### Reason for asking

It just bothers me whenever I **rebuild** or **clean** the solution to see these **warnings** both in my "Razor View" and in the "Error list" when nothing seems to be wrong from my point of view.

What am I missing?

These are the versions:

- Visual Studio 15.9.7
- .NET Framework 4.7.03056

Comment: My guess...it could be because [max](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_progress_max.asp) and value should be floating point numbers.

Comment: Where is your class implementation for `ICarList` interface?

Comment: @habib The implementation of the interface doesn't matter for this – the Razor Engine shouldn't care about it just as with plain C#. Also, there's nothing too crazy in `CarList`: just the properties that you saw in the interface and one constructor.

Comment: Maybe that's the reason, @Reniuz. In my mind, the Razor Engine should treat any number (`int`, `double` or `float`) the same for this kind of HTML attributes, but who knows... I will try changing it to `float` and see if the warnings still persist. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Reniuz I've just changed those two `int` properties to `float` and after **cleaning** and **rebulding** the solution, I got the same warnings.

Comment: I did some testing. This is strange behavior. Sometimes it shows warn sometimes - not. See an [image](https://imgur.com/wWaUaP7). VS version same. framework 4.6.1

Comment: Found when warn permanently disappears - after adding space after last `"` so  `<progress max="@Model.Value">` changed to `<progress max="@Model.Value" >` and then deleted that space before `>`

Comment: @Reniuz First of all, this is a strange behavior as you said. Still, I know that there are some problems with **Razor** in Visual Studio. But, these problems are related to **copying and pasting** code not with showing warnings when there aren't supposed to be (I heard this from a Microsoft developer in a podcast). So, I tried what you said and it worked :)), but if I close the file and open it again, the warnings reappear.